# Using Map For Aggregation in Spark JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Data with Columns below

```
dataset.show();
+---------+------+--------------+------+--------------------------+
|  Col1   | Col2 | Acceleration | Mass | Force(Acceleration*Mass) |
+---------+------+--------------+------+--------------------------+
| weight1 | ex1  |           10 |    5 |                       50 |
| weight1 | ex2  |            8 |    4 |                       32 |
| weight2 | ex1  |            5 |    3 |                       15 |
| weight2 | ex2  |            9 |    4 |                       36 |
+---------+------+--------------+------+--------------------------+
```

I use a aggMap as below.

```
aggMap.put("Acceleration","sum");
aggMap.put("Mass","sum");
```

for **Force** I want it to be calculated always as `Acceleration*Mass`, How can I pass this in a `aggMap`(Here I'm not passing as I am unable to do)

In java I do groupby as

```
dataset=dataset.select(col("Col1")).groupBy(col("Col1")).agg(aggMap);
```

and the result I get as

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------+
|  Col1   | sum(Acceleration) | sum(Mass) |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+
| weight1 |                18 |         9 |
| weight2 |                14 |         7 |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

But these columns need to modified `sum(Acceleration) as Acceleration` and `sum(Mass) as Mass`
and I want column of Force to be calculated in the aggregation and should come as `Force`

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------+-------+
|  Col1   | sum(Acceleration) | sum(Mass) | Force |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+-------+
| weight1 |                18 |         9 |   172 |
| weight2 |                14 |         7 |    98 |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+-------+
```

How Can I achieve the Same?
I'm doing Map because I am getting the Column Names (force,mass,Accele..) dynamically, Its not every time I have to compute.So I'll check if I need only Acceleration or Mass or Both or All three.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  val df = Seq(
    ("weight1", "ex1", 10, 5),
    ("weight1", "ex2", 8, 4),
    ("weight2", "ex1", 5, 3),
    ("weight2", "ex2", 9, 4)
  ).toDF("Col1", "Col2", "Acceleration", "Mass")

  val newDF = df.groupBy($"Col1")
    .agg(sum($"Acceleration").as("Acceleration"), sum($"Mass").as("Mass"))
    .withColumn("Force", $"Acceleration" * $"Mass")

  newDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------+----+-----+
|Col1   |Acceleration|Mass|Force|
+-------+------------+----+-----+
|weight2|14          |7   |98   |
|weight1|18          |9   |162  |
+-------+------------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Yeah Shankar . This I cannot create Dynamically right. I this when I know for sure that I want all three. But when I have to make it generic if I need only Mass,Acceleration.Force..

Comment: I need to pass as like Map Shankar.

Comment: I don't think that is possible

Comment: Oh My bad :(  I could do for Mass and Acceleration. :(  except that renaming.

Comment: Shankar, Can I send `sum($"Acceleration").as("Acceleration"), sum($"Mass").as("Mass")` as Seq by adding to a List or Something?